# htaccess issue in accessing the directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My Blog link is http://www.example.com/blog when i am trying to access it it converts the url into http://www.example.com/blog/?ID=blog which is not correct. But when i put the backslash at the end of the blog it works fine but i don't want this back slash at the end

I try to change every thing inside htaccess file but failed.

Here is my htaccess file

```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d [OR]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
   RewriteRule ^products products.php
   RewriteRule ^websitemap sitemap.php
   RewriteRule ^aboutus aboutus.php
   RewriteRule ^clients clients.php
   RewriteRule ^shoppingcart inq.php
   RewriteRule ^contactus contact.php
   RewriteRule ^finished finished.php
   RewriteRule ^product/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ product_large.php?ID=$1

   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ category.php?ID=$1
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ products.php?ID=$2&MID=$1

   ErrorDocument 404     http://www.example.co.uk/error404.php

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$
   RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.example\.co\.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule after `RewriteRule ^ - [L]` to force a trailing slash:

```
DirectorySlash On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?)[^/][?\s]
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^blog(/.*)?$ - [L,NC]

# your rest of the rules
```

Comment: Do you have .htaccess in `/blog/` also?

Comment: I installed the wordpress blog in sub folder called blog. and i didn't find any htaccess file there

Comment: That means `/blog/.htaccess` also must be there, can you post its content here.

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

its the code of Blog Htaccess file

Comment: No luck my dear. its the same

Comment: Sorry dear still no success

Comment: I don't see any rule that converts `/blog/` to `/blog/ID=blog` and I cannot guess your local setup

Comment: Very sorry dear. I was wrong. actually i forgot to clear my chache that's why it was not working but your last code works fine. 
Thanks alot for you help